# How to find the cause of multiple apache processes - Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run an Amazon EC2 panel through my Webmin control panel. Recently we have experienced problems with the server running out of memory and I have identified a rather alarming breakdown of running processes.

[image]

Could anyone help me with a tip on how to find the cause of this problem? Our server set up has been running perfectly for almost 6 months without going down.

Comment: can you paste `httpd.conf` file for reference?

Comment: which apache version you're using ?

Comment: Have you done any analysis of your apache access and error logs?  Any unusual or heavy traffic?

Comment: Apache (httpd) is designed to spawn multiple instances to handle heavy loads.  The behavior shown in your post is not that unusual.  How many instances of httpd may be spawned can be set in your httpd.conf, and since this is an indication that you may be encountering a lot of traffic that's why you need to take a close look at your Apache logs as the others have indicated.  Without that additional information there's no way anybody can help you out.